# How do I create a pip requirements file for a tarball on my local filesystem?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, requirements.txt

Tell me if what I'm trying to do doesn't make sense.

I want to create a virtual environment that, among other things, includes MySQLDb 1.2.3.  This library is distributed as a gzipped tarball (.tgz) file.  I want to install everything—including tarballs on my local filesystem—from a requirements file in requirements/apps.txt (this is based on a setup I saw in http://thraxil.org/users/anders/posts/2009/06/12/Django-Deployment-with-virtualenv-and-pip/):

```
pip.py install -E ve --enable-site-packages --requirement requirements/apps.txt
```

I couldn't find any documentation on the pip requirements file format for local files.

What does the requirements file (`apps.txt`) need to contain if the directory `requirements/` contains the file `MySQL-python-1.2.3.tgz`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use absolute/relative paths in [requirements files](http://pip.openplans.org/requirement-format.html) e.g.:

```
--extra-index-url=http://example.com
my-apps/apps1.tar.gz
# put apps2-1.0.1.tar.gz to http://example.com/apps2/
apps2
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add -f file:/absolute/path/to/the/directory/that/contains/your/downloaded/tarball/ to your call to pip.

The requirements file has to contain:

MySQL-python==1.2.3

plus everything else you want to install